# React Jest --coverage ignore

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

My folder/ project structure for reusable components (i.e. field types) looks like this:

1. /fields
2. /fields/text
3. /fields/radio
4. /fields/checkbox
5. /fields/...
6. /fields/index.jsx (which only reexports each of above for simpler importing purposes)

now when i run jet --coverage i get index.jsx which is just a import/export proxy included into coverage report, is there a way to configure jest runner to ignore "such" files ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could add the filename to [`coveragePathIgnorePatterns`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#coveragepathignorepatterns-array-string) list of your jest settings

```
coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['/fields/index.jsx'],
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I found:

First (already mentioned by @andreas-köberle) is ignoring files using config or CLI instruction.

Another one is writing some dummy tests:

```js
import {Stuff} from '../index';

describe('check', () => {
    it('reexports', () => {
        expect(Stuff).toBeTruthy();
    });
})
```

I found this one preferable. In case you write some logic in your reexports-file it reminds you to cover it with tests.